# connect WSO2 integration studio with remote server WSO2 Mi

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-micro-integrator

I made an API on integration studio on my local computer, Now I want to deploy API on WSO2 MI that is on remote server. I added server and chose WSO2 Remote Server and set other configs, but when server is started and CompositeExporter is synced, nothing happened on MI and API is not there.
I do not know what is wrong.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.2.0/micro-integrator/develop/using-remote-micro-integrator/ documentation to add remote EI or MI server into Integration Studio. Once you integrate a server, follow the below steps.

1. Open the  **Servers** view (Windows > Show Views > Servers)
2. right-click on the added server and select **Add or Remove** option
3. Select Composite Exporter module to be packed.

Comment: connection to EI is ok, but can not connect to MI.