# How can I connect to a MI via Integration Studio?

Tags: wso2, wso2-micro-integrator

I am trying to connect MI via Integration Studio. I downloaded [MI](https://wso2.com/integration/micro-integrator/) and ran micro-integrator.bat. to start MI.

```
C:\Users\yusuf.avci_alo-tech\Downloads\wso2mi-4.0.0\bin>micro-integrator.bat
[2021-12-02 11:41:29,367]  INFO {EventAdminConfigurationNotifier} - Logging configuration changed. (Event Admin service unavailable - no notification sent).
[2021-12-02 11:41:31,763]  INFO {AppDeployerServiceComponent} - Dashboard is configured. Initiating heartbeat component.
[2021-12-02 11:41:31,791]  INFO {PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager} - Pass-through HTTP Listener started on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8290
[2021-12-02 11:41:31,796]  INFO {PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager} - Pass-through HTTPS Listener started on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8253
[2021-12-02 11:41:31,797]  INFO {StartupFinalizer} - WSO2 Micro Integrator started in 4,08 seconds
[2021-12-02 11:41:31,878]  INFO {PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager} - Pass-through EI_INTERNAL_HTTP_INBOUND_ENDPOINT Listener started on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9201
[2021-12-02 11:41:31,888]  INFO {PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager} - Pass-through EI_INTERNAL_HTTPS_INBOUND_ENDPOINT Listener started on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9164
```

Then, I try to add server in Integration Studio.

[Define New Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYN9u.png)
[Entering The Ports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBg2L.png)

When I try to connect the server, I encounter this error:

```
Working directory does not exist: runtime/microesb
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I deploy an integration project created in Integration Studio to a MI server other than the embedden one?

Note: I've found a similar question, but the answer wasn't useful for me:
[connect WSO2 integration studio with remote server WSO2 Mi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67486054/connect-wso2-integration-studio-with-remote-server-wso2-mi)

Answer (score 0):

In the "Define a New Server" popup, click on Add link next to "Server Runtime Environment", and then point the CARBON_HOME to the folder where MI is installed.
This will fix this issue.